# Rigorous Proof of Cut Property $\Rightarrow$ Completeness of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Abbott's book states that $\mathbb{R}$ possess the following property.

> Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be nonempty sets such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then, there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\leq c$ if $x\in A$ and $x\geq c$ if $x\in B$.

An exercise asks to prove that the axiom of completeness (that is to say that all sets bounded above have a least upper bound) implies the above property (the Cut Property of $\mathbb{R}$) and then the other way around. While I understand the forward direction, there seems to be several holes in my reverse argument.

Here is my attempt:

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty set that is bounded above, and assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has the cut property. Consider the set $B=\lbrace b\in\mathbb{R} | b\geq a \forall a\in A \rbrace$, of all upper bounds to $A$. We would like $A\cup B$ to fill $\mathbb{R}$. To accomplish this, define a set $A'=B^C=\bigcup\limits_{a\in A}(-\infty, a)$. We have that $A'\cup B=\mathbb{R}$, thus the cut property applies to these two sets. There exists a number $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\leq c$ for all $a\in A'$, and $b\geq c$ for all $b\in B$. As $B$ is the set of all upper bounds to $A$, it follows that $c=\sup(A)$.

Several points of the proof that I am unsure of:

- Is the construction of $A'$ appropriate here?
- I feel that I draw a conclusion too quickly, without enough rigor. Where am I skipping steps?

Comment: Is there a missing condition? What if I take $A = \mathbb Q$ and $B = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$? Then no such $c$ exists.

Comment: The missing condition might be that $A$ and $B$ are half-lines. Except for that, the reasoning seems all right. Where do you _feel_ the gap?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut for a correct definition

Comment: Your cut property has something missing (this is probably an issue with you typing in haste and not a misprint in the book). You need to mention that every member of $A$ is less than every member of $B$. Dedekind gave this theorem as his version of completeness in his paper *Stetigkeit under irrationale zahlen* where he introduced the idea of a cut (*schnitt*). Your proof is however correct. You can perhaps explicitly show that $A', B$ satisfy all the properties of a cut.

Comment: Never not repost: https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4483